# Insert To Access Database Not Working

Tags: database, vb.net, insert

I have a problem inserting a row into a table. When I click the register button, the row is not in the database, but in Gridview, it shows the row is inserted. When I open the database after clicking the register button, Gridview removes or clones the new insert data. I have made many programs and have not seen this problem before!

My code is below.

```
 Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdb"
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conn)
    Dim query As String
    Dim adb As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    con.Open()
    query = "INSERT INTO Sell(Seller,Price) Values(11,10)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    con.Close()
```

The VB.NET compiler is not giving me an error and I'm not getting an error when I run the program.

---

I'M change run as debug to run as release

Comment: Why Are You Writing Like This?

Comment: Because i have Problem

Comment: Is this a winforms application?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the DataDirectory substitution string you should remember that for a WinForms application during a debug session inside Visual Studio the database used is located in the `PROJECTFOLDER\BIN\DEBUG` (or x86 variant if it is the case) not in the database located in the `PROJECTFOLDER`.

Source [Where is DataDirectory?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce)

Comment: Thank You Changed To Release